# How to define Stack props for a screen that contains NativeStackScreenProps on React Navigation v6?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have this stack props `type`:

```
export type OrderSetupStackProps = {
  SetupDeliveryScheduleScreen: undefined;
  OrderSetupMultiStepFormStackScreen: undefined;
  OrderSetupSuccessScreen: undefined;
};
```

Which I am using like this: `const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator<OrderSetupStackProps>();`

This is my interface for my `SetupDeliveryScheduleScreen`:

```
export interface SetupDeliveryScheduleScreenProps
  extends NativeStackScreenProps<
    RootStackScreenProps,
    "OrderSetupStack",
    "SetupDeliveryScheduleScreen"
  > {}
```

I'm using it like this:

```
const SetupDeliveryScheduleScreen = ({
  navigation,
}: SetupDeliveryScheduleScreenProps) => { 
   ... // other code ... 
}
```

In this code below:

```
      <Stack.Screen
        name="SetupDeliveryScheduleScreen"
        component={SetupDeliveryScheduleScreen}
        options={{
          headerShown: true,
          headerTransparent: true,
          headerTitle: "",
          headerLeft: () => <NavigationBackArrow />,
        }}
      />
```

I'm getting the following error:

> Type '({ navigation, }: SetupDeliveryScheduleScreenProps) => JSX.Element' is not assignable to type 'ScreenComponentType<OrderSetupStackProps, "SetupDeliveryScheduleScreen"> | undefined'.
> Type '({ navigation, }: SetupDeliveryScheduleScreenProps) => JSX.Element' is not assignable to type 'FunctionComponent<{}>'.
> Types of parameters '__0' and 'props' are incompatible.
> Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'NativeStackScreenProps<RootStackScreenProps, "OrderSetupStack", "SetupDeliveryScheduleScreen">': navigation, route

I believe it's because my `OrderSetupStackProps` declares the `SetupDeliveryScheduleScreen` route params as `undefined`. But I tried to import `SetupDeliveryScheduleScreenProps` like so:

```
export type OrderSetupStackProps = {
  SetupDeliveryScheduleScreen: SetupDeliveryScheduleScreenProps;
};
```

But it still doesn't work